# How does the ISO Prolog standard require the preservation of variable identity when converting from a clause to a term?

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog

I am missing something in my reading of *ISO/IEC 13211-1*, subclauses 7.6.3 and 7.6.4:

> ### 7.6.3 Converting the head of a clause to a term
>
> A head `H` with predicate indicator `P/N` can be converted to a term `T`:
>
> a) If `N` is zero then `T` is the atom `P`.
>
> b) If `N` is non-zero then `T` is a renamed copy (7.1.6.2) of `TT` where `TT` is the compound term whose principal functor is `P/N` and the arguments of `H` and `TT` are identical.
>
> ### 7.6.4 Converting the body of a clause to a term
>
> A goal `G` which is a predication with predicate indicator `P/N` can be converted to a term `T`:
>
> a) If `N` is zero then `T` is the atom `P`.
>
> b) If `N` is non-zero then `T` is a renamed copy (7.1.6.2) of `TT` where `TT` is the compound term whose principal functor is `P/N` and the arguments of `G` and `TT` are identical.
>
> c) If `G` is a control construct which appears in table 9 then `T` is a term with the corresponding principal functor. If the principal functor of `T` is `call/1` or `catch/3` or `throw/1` then the arguments of `G` and `T` are identical, else if the principal functor of `T` is `(',')/2` or `(;)/2` or `(->)/2` then each argument of `G` shall also be converted to a term.

Suppose we have a public (7.5.3) (e.g. dynamic) user-defined predicate `a/1`, defined by the following single clause:

```
a(X) :- b(X).
```

Clearly, the goal

```
?- clause(a(A), b(B)), A == B.
```

should succeed. Quoting part of the definition of `clause/2` (8.8.1.1):

> a) Searches sequentially through each public user-defined procedure in the database and creates a list `L` of all the terms `clause(H, B)` such that
>
> 1) the database contains a clause whose head can be converted to a term `H` (7.6.3), and whose body can be converted to a term `B` (7.6.4), and
>
> 2) `H` unifies with `Head`, and
>
> 3) `B` unifies with `Body`.

Converting the head of the above clause to a term, 7.6.3 b) applies, and we create a renamed copy `a(A)` of `a(X)`. Similarly, converting the body of the clause, 7.6.4 b) applies, and we create a renamed copy `b(B)` of `b(X)`.

The problem is that `a(A)` and `b(B)` are separate renamed copies. How is it required that `A` and `B` are identical variables, as we would expect?

The same question could be asked for a clause

```
p :- q(X), r(X).
```

When we convert the body of this clause to a term, 7.6.4 c) applies, and the principal functor of the term should be `(',')/2`, with the two arguments being the goals `q(X)` and `r(X)` converted to terms. But these are predications and 7.6.4 b) applies, so again the two resulting terms are separately renamed copies.

What am I missing?

Comment: Essentially, you are right. However, in 8.8.1.1 there is first a declarative description that explicitly mentions the term `H :- B` and the term `Head :- Body` that should unify. So here, the problem is avoided.

Comment: @false: So is this a known issue? Is it likely to be fixed in a corrigendum?

Comment: It is now known. In contrast to [your previous find](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/post-cor3#1), this one is somewhat more serious. Yet, it most probably will be corrected after Cor.3.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry I seem to keep finding such things. I hope this is the last one.

Comment: That's fine! Who knows what you will find next!